# Java rmi exporting an object

Tags: java, dictionary, rmi

I have a problem:

I've done a server that have a Map object.
I want to registry with rmi that object from the server to be accessible everywhere. The methods that I want for rmi register are Map Get() and Set(Map). The first one has to return the Map of the server and the second one has to change the Map of the server with the new one.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Poor design. Every client will get his own copy, update it in his own way, send it to the server, and clobber the previous client's update. It won't work.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you must define a interface like the following:

```
public interface RmiMap extends Remote {
       Map<K, E> get() throws RemoteException;
       void set(Map<K, E> map) throws RemoteException;
}
```

The importent parts are the `Remote` Interface and the `RemoteException`. Furthermore the `Map`-Object must implement `Serializable` so I recommand to encapsulate the `Map`-Object in a own object.

An another class must implement this interface and then register this implementation at the RMI-Registry.

```
LocateRegistry.createRegistry(Registry.REGISTRY_PORT);
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();

RmiMap stub = (RmiMap) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(RmiMapImplementation, 0);
registry.rebind("RmiMap", stub);
```

Then you can access the interface from a remote host.

```
RmiMap rmiMap = (RmiMap) remoteRegistry.lookup("RmiMap");
```

This should give you a brief introduction into RMI.

Comment: Most if not all the Map implementations in the JDK already implement `Serializable.`